# Nvidia GPU driver won't compile from RPM

Tags: compiling, nvidia, rpm, opensuse, cuda

I recently update from OpenSuSE 15.3 to 15.4 including a GPU update to be able to use the new drivers (beyond version 490). Since this upgrade the kernel module is not updated by any RPM base install. I got my GUI working again using the `.run` installer, but this is requires me to update the driver manually and leads to havoc with the RPM based management of the CUDA installation.

So I would like to know a way to get this working again.

My first step was to try to install the RPM directly via `rpm -i --force ./nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default-525.85.12_k4.12.14_lp150.12.82-0.x86_64.rpm >/tmp/intall_nvidia.log 2>&1`.
Here is the relevant part of the install log:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-5.14.21-150400.24.41-obj/x86_64/default'
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-5.14.21-150400.24.41-obj/x86_64/default'
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m1Ftk9: line 11: pushd: not found
make: Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile'.  Stop.
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.m1Ftk9: line 16: popd: not found
rm: cannot remove '/lib/modules/5.14.21-150400.24.41-default/updates/nvidia*.ko': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat '/usr/src/kernel-modules/nvidia-525.85.12-default/nvidia*.ko': No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /lib/modules/4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default: No such file or directory

Modprobe blacklist files have been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau from loading. This can be reverted by deleting /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-*.conf.

*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can be loaded. ***

grep: /etc/sysconfig/kernel: No such file or directory
warning: %post(nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default-525.85.12_k4.12.14_lp150.12.82-0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
dracut: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut --kver=4.12.14-lp150.12.82-default -f
...
# A buch of dracat output
...
dracut: *** Creating initramfs image file '/boot/initrd-5.14.21-150400.24.41-default' done ***
warning: %posttrans(nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default-525.85.12_k4.12.14_lp150.12.82-0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
```

Which tells me that the module is somehow not compiling (why it is missing bash build-in commands I cannot fathom).
So I unpacked the RPM, went to the build directory `./unpacked/usr/src/kernel-modules/nvidia-525.85.12-default/` and did run `make`.
I got a fine build, `nvidia.ko` and its siblings, return value `0` and only some minor warnings about minor coding problems (unused variables, implicit-fallthrough and similar).

Well, so it seems to me like the RPM is fine and something else is running wild.

I do have no idea where to fix this so any hind would be a godsend.

Kind regards

Comment: I'll hazard a guess and say you have not installed the kernel source. You also appear to have old kernels installed, remove them.

Comment: @Bib The source for `5.14.21-150400.24.41` is installed (I at least checked the directories and looked into the boot code). The source for `4.12.14-lp150.12.82` is not installed, but the only place I was able to find references to this kernel version is the `nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default-525.85.12_k4.12.14_lp150.12.82-0.x86_64.rpm`. Strangely the name implies some connection to this kernel version. PS: I may clarify that by doing by hand what the RPM should do I am able to get kernel modules without trouble.

Comment: The `nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default-525.85.12_k4.12.14_lp150.12.82-0.x86_64.rpm` suggests it's for 15.0. Are you sure the repo is `https://download.nvidia.com/opensuse/leap/15.4/` as that file is not listed there. Unless you have some compelling reason to download & install manually, I would just set the repo up and let the system work it all out.

Comment: Well, no. I am using CUDA, so I need the developer drivers from `https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/opensuse15/`, where only one folder for all opensuse 15 is provided.